# preferred language/technique for sequence processing or parsing

Tags: java, parsing

I have come across similar problems a few times in the past and want to know what language (methodology) if any is used to solve similar problems (I am a J2EE/java developer):

problem: Out of a probable set of words, with a given rule (say the word can be a combination of A and X, and always starts with a X, each word is delimited by a space), you have to read a sequence of words and parse through the input to decide which of the words are syntatctically correct. In a nutshell these are problems that involve parsing techniques. Say simulate the logic of an vending machine in Java.

So what I want to know is what are the techniques/best approach to solve problems pertaining to parsing inputs. Like alien language processing problem in google code jam

[Google code jam problem](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=90101#s=p0)

Do we use something like ANTLR or some library in java.

I know this question is slightly generic, but I had no other way of expressing it.

P.S: I do not want a solution, I am looking for best way to solve such recurring problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaCC for complex parsing.

For relative simple parsing and event processing I use enum(s) as a state machine. esp as a push parser.

For very simple parsing, you can use indexOf or split(" ") with equals, switch or startsWith

Comment: are you talking about approach like this: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/java-secret-using-enum-to-build-state.html

Comment: Since I write it, I did have that in mind. ;) The second half is an example of using an enum as a state machine.

Comment: great Peter.. +1, I did try it in past, but could not understand it well. Let me try again.

Comment: Happy to take any specific questions if you have any simple examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate the logic of a something that is essentially a finite state automation, you can simply code the FSA by hand.  This is a standard computer science solution.  A less obvious way to do this is to use a lexer-generator (there are lots of them) to generate the FSA from descriptions of the valid sequences of events (in lexer-generator speak, these are called "characters" but you can cheat and substitute event occurrences for characters).

If you have complex recursive rules about matching, you'll want a more traditional parser.
You can code these by hand, too, if the grammar isn't complicated; see my [?SO answer on "how to build a recursive descent parser"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163).  If your grammar is complex or it changes quickly, you'll want to use a standard parser generator.  Other answers here suggest specific ones but there are many to choose from, all generally very capable.

[FWIW, I applied parser generators to recognizing valid transaction sequences in 1974 in  TRW POS terminals the May Company department store.  Worked pretty well.]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANTLR which is good, It will help in complex problem But you can also use regular expressions eg: spilt("\\s+").